Paytm Payment Gateway, System Error (code: 00000900) in initiate Transaction API using Go
I'm currently working on integrating the Paytm payment gateway, and I'm encountering an issue while trying to generate the transaction token.
I'm using the following endpoint for the transaction token:
https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/api/v1/initiateTransaction?mid=<mid>&orderId=<orderID>
Here’s the request body I’m sending:
{
    "requestType": "Payment",
    "mid": "<mid>",
    "websiteName": "WEBSTAGING",
    "orderId": "<orderID>",
    "txnAmount": {
        "value": 99.00,
        "currency": "INR"
    },
    "userInfo": {
        "custId": "CUST_001",
        "email": "user110402@gmail.com"
    },
    "callbackUrl": "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=<orderID>"
}

req.Header.Set("signature", paytmChecksum)
req.Header.Set("channelId", os.Getenv("Channel_Id")) //Added the checksum and the channelid as Headers

I’ve double-checked the request parameters to ensure they match the documentation and the MID, OrderId, checksum as well, but I'm still getting a “System error” (resultCode: 00000900).
Complete Response :
{
    "head": {
        "requestId": null,
        "responseTimestamp": "1729169863953",
        "version": "v1"
    },
    "body": {
        "extraParamsMap": null,
        "resultInfo": {
            "resultStatus": "U",
            "resultCode": "00000900",
            "resultMsg": "System error"
        }
    }
}

What did I try?

I followed Paytm's documentation and constructed the API request to the Paytm staging URL https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/api/v1/initiateTransaction.
I passed the necessary parameters, including mid, orderId, txnAmount, userInfo, and callbackUrl, in the request body.
I also tried changing the callbackUrl to different variations, such as Paytm's provided callback URL and an ngrok URL (https://ngrok-url/v1/verifyTransaction), to ensure my callback was correctly handled.
I checked multiple sources and examples (e.g., GitHub repos, Stack Overflow posts) where people used similar APIs, and I aligned my code with those examples.

What was I expecting?
I was expecting the Paytm server to generate and return a transaction token that I could use for further processing. Instead, I received a System error with the result code 00000900, and I'm not sure why this is happening.
